# Table with vertical aligned header text [tabularx]

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, luatex, tabularx

In `LuaTeX` with document class `memoir` and use of `tabularx`, how do I go about making a table (*linewidth*) layout similar to:

[image]

Note:

- Table head is center bottom align
- Table body is right align
- A group of three rows are grouped with a double vertical rule
- Some cells have a normal `\footnote{}` reference

Comment: Without a minimal compilable code, it's hard  to say. For the footnotes,problem, try the `tablefootnote` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following MWE that was achieved  with a combination of `siunitx`, `rotating` and `makecell` might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-align-text-post = false}

\begin{document}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Some Text}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=2]||
                 S[table-format=2]|
                 S[table-format=3, table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{11}]|}
\hline
\rothead{Some text} & \rothead{other text}& \rothead{more text more text more text} \\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\
11 & 12 & 133\\
11 & 12 & 133\footnotemark\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext{Some footnote text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Note that ```\footnotemark``` and ```\footnotetext``` will run side-ways, that is, numbering won't follow a vertical chronological order but across each row. Most likely you'll be better of with your own (manuel) footnote numbering/markers.

Answer (score 1):

You may even typeset this tabular by using [cals](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals). However, the footnotes need special treatment. I defined a new command that pushes the right aligned cell content to the left to give space for two digits footnote markers. If you need ‘real’ footnotes, you may use the [footnote](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footnote) packages from the [mdwtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdwtools) bundle, which gives footnotes at the bottom of the page together with other footnotes. However, as you have noticed, your footnotes are numbered vertically, so I assume you have to fake the them using `\textsuperscript`.

I have used the [MinionPro](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/MinionPro) package to have oldstyle (text) figures, like your original tabular. You find olstyle figueres in other fonts, too. If you use ordinary (lining) figures, you should use `\vfill` instead of `\vfil`, to align the cell content at the bottom. If not, cells with footnote markers do not line up. See additional comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[DIV=12, british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[letterspace=100,%
                babel=true,%
                tracking=true,%
                kerning=true]%
        {microtype}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cals}
\usepackage{rotating}

\let\nc=\nullcell                   % CALS shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\addtokomafont{caption}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalfont}

\newcommand{\roth}[1]{\begin{sideways}\parbox{2.2cm}{\raggedright #1}\end{sideways}}
% The macro rotates and right aligns the cell content
\newcommand{\croth}[1]{\begin{sideways}\parbox{2.2cm}{\centering #1}\end{sideways}}
% The macro rotates and centres the cell content
\newcommand{\rlb}[1]{\makebox[6.5pt][l]{\kern0.05em#1}}
% Move cell content to the left. Right aligns figures and leave toom for left aligned footnotemarks

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}
\begin{calstable}[c] % Centred calstable

% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123\relax}           % A very narrow column to fake double vertical line
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/123*10\relax}
    }

% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all multiplicators are 123

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside horizontal rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}   % Outside vertical rules
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}    % Rule between header and body
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}        % Inside vertical rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0pt}          % Inside horizontal rules
\def\cals@bgcolor{}              % May be removed since we do not use colour 
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil{}}   % Cell content aligned at bottom, necessary to align cells with
                                 % footnotes. If you do not use oldstyle (text) figures, change to `\vfill`
                                 % to align cell content to bottom
%\setlength{\cals@paddingT}{3pt} % If you prefer a more vertically compact tabular, you may 
%                                % change top and bottom (row) padding
%\setlength{\cals@paddingB}{3pt}

%R1H1
\thead{%
\brow
\alignC\cell{\croth{\vfil According to Jaláluddin.}}
\cell{\croth{\vfil According to Noêldeke.}}
\cell{\croth{\vfil According to Muir.}}
\cell{}                            % A narrow cell fakes double vertical rules
\cell{\roth{\vfil Jaláluddin.}}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Noêldeke.}}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Muir.}}
\cell{}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Jaláluddin.}}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Noêldeke.}}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Muir.}}
\cell{}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Jaláluddin.}}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Noêldeke.}}
\cell{\roth{\vfil Muir.}}
\erow
}
%R2B1
\brow
\alignR\cell{96\rlb{}}         % Start all rows with alignment command to avoid surprises at page breaks
\cell{96\rlb{}}
\cell{103\rlb{\textsuperscript{1}}}
\cell{}
\cell{75\rlb{}}
\cell{100\rlb{}}
\cell{110\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{40\rlb{}}
\cell{38\rlb{}}
\cell{37\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{3\rlb{}}
\cell{46\rlb{}}
\cell{16\rlb{}}
\erow
%R3B2
\brow
\alignR\cell{68\rlb{}}
\cell{74\rlb{}}
\cell{100\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{104\rlb{}}
\cell{79\rlb{}}
\cell{85\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{41\rlb{}}
\cell{36\rlb{}}
\cell{30\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{33\rlb{}}
\cell{6\rlb{}}
\cell{13\rlb{}}
\erow
%R4B3
\brow
\alignR\cell{73\rlb{}}
\cell{111\rlb{}}
\cell{99\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{77\rlb{}}
\cell{77\rlb{}}
\cell{83\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{42\rlb{}}
\cell{43\rlb{}}
\cell{26\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{60\rlb{}}
\cell{13\rlb{}}
\cell{29\rlb{}}
\erow
%R5B4
\brow
\alignR\cell{74\rlb{}}
\cell{106\rlb{}}
\cell{91\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{50\rlb{}}
\cell{78\rlb{}}
\cell{78\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{43\rlb{}}
\cell{72\rlb{}}
\cell{15\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{4\rlb{}}
\cell{2\rlb{\textsuperscript{12}}}
\cell{7\rlb{}}
\erow
%R6B5
\brow
\alignR\cell{111\rlb{}}
\cell{108\rlb{}}
\cell{106\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{90\rlb{}}
\cell{88\rlb{}}
\cell{77\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{44\rlb{}}
\cell{67\rlb{}}
\cell{51\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{99\rlb{}}
\cell{98\rlb{}}
\cell{113\rlb{}}
\erow
%R7B6
\brow
\alignR\cell{81\rlb{}}
\cell{104\rlb{}}
\cell{1\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{86\rlb{}}
\cell{89\rlb{}}
\cell{76\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{45\rlb{}}
\cell{23\rlb{}}
\cell{46\rlb{\textsuperscript{9}}}
\cell{}
\cell{57\rlb{}}
\cell{64\rlb{}}
\cell{114\rlb{}}
\erow
%R8B7
\brow
\alignR\cell{87\rlb{}}
\cell{107\rlb{}}
\cell{101\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{54\rlb{}}
\cell{75\rlb{}}
\cell{75\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{46\rlb{}}
\cell{21\rlb{}}
\cell{72\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{47\rlb{}}
\cell{62\rlb{}}
\cell{98\rlb{\textsuperscript{13}}}
\erow
%R9B8
\brow
\alignR\cell{92\rlb{}}
\cell{102\rlb{}}
\cell{95\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{38\rlb{}}
\cell{83\rlb{}}
\cell{70\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{51\rlb{}}
\cell{25\rlb{}}
\cell{35\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{62\rlb{}}
\cell{8\rlb{}}
\cell{2\rlb{}}
\erow
%R10B9
\brow
\alignR\cell{89\rlb{}}
\cell{105\rlb{}}
\cell{102\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{7\rlb{}}
\cell{69\rlb{}}
\cell{109\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{88\rlb{}}
\cell{17\rlb{}}
\cell{36\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{55\rlb{}}
\cell{47\rlb{}}
\cell{3\rlb{}}
\erow
%R11B10
\brow
\alignR\cell{93\rlb{}}
\cell{92\rlb{}}
\cell{104\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{72\rlb{}}
\cell{51\rlb{}}
\cell{107\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{18\rlb{}}
\cell{27\rlb{}}
\cell{19\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{76\rlb{}}
\cell{3\rlb{}}
\cell{8\rlb{}}
\erow
%R12B11
\brow
\alignR\cell{94\rlb{}}
\cell{90\rlb{}}
\cell{82\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{36\rlb{}}
\cell{52\rlb{}}
\cell{55\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{16\rlb{}}
\cell{18\rlb{}}
\cell{18\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{13\rlb{}}
\cell{61\rlb{}}
\cell{47\rlb{}}
\erow
%R13B12
\brow
\alignR\cell{103\rlb{}}
\cell{94\rlb{}}
\cell{92\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{25\rlb{}}
\cell{56\rlb{}}
\cell{56\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{71\rlb{}}
\cell{32\rlb{\textsuperscript{8}}}
\cell{27\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{98\rlb{}}
\cell{57\rlb{}}
\cell{62\rlb{}}
\erow
%R14B13
\brow
\alignR\cell{100\rlb{}}
\cell{93\rlb{}}
\cell{105\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{35\rlb{}}
\cell{70\rlb{}}
\cell{67\rlb{\textsuperscript{7}}}
\cell{}
\cell{14\rlb{}}
\cell{41\rlb{}}
\cell{42\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{59\rlb{}}
\cell{4\rlb{}}
\cell{5\rlb{}}
\erow
%R15B14
\brow
\alignR\cell{108\rlb{}}
\cell{97\rlb{}}
\cell{89\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{19\rlb{}}
\cell{55\rlb{}}
\cell{53\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{21\rlb{}}
\cell{45\rlb{}}
\cell{40\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{110\rlb{}}
\cell{65\rlb{}}
\cell{59\rlb{}}
\erow
%R16B15
\brow
\alignR\cell{102\rlb{}}
\cell{86\rlb{}}
\cell{90\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{20\rlb{}}
\cell{112\rlb{}}
\cell{32\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{23\rlb{}}
\cell{16\rlb{}}
\cell{38\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{24\rlb{}}
\cell{59\rlb{}}
\cell{4\rlb{}}
\erow
%R17B16
\brow
\alignR\cell{107\rlb{}}
\cell{91\rlb{}}
\cell{93\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{56\rlb{}}
\cell{109\rlb{}}
\cell{39\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{32\rlb{}}
\cell{30\rlb{}}
\cell{25\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{22\rlb{}}
\cell{33\rlb{}}
\cell{58\rlb{}}
\erow
%R18B17
\brow
\alignR\cell{109\rlb{}}
\cell{80\rlb{}}
\cell{94\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{26\rlb{}}
\cell{113\rlb{\textsuperscript{4}}}
\cell{73\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{52\rlb{}}
\cell{11\rlb{}}
\cell{20\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{63\rlb{}}
\cell{63\rlb{}}
\cell{65\rlb{}}
\erow
%R19B17
\brow
\alignR\cell{105\rlb{}}
\cell{68\rlb{}}
\cell{108\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{27\rlb{}}
\cell{114\rlb{\textsuperscript{5}}}
\cell{79\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{67\rlb{}}
\cell{14\rlb{}}
\cell{43\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{58\rlb{}}
\cell{24\rlb{}}
\cell{63\rlb{}}
\erow
%R20B19
\brow
\alignR\cell{113\rlb{}}
\cell{87\rlb{}}
\cell{96\rlb{\textsuperscript{2}}}
\cell{}
\cell{28\rlb{}}
\cell{1\rlb{}}
\cell{54\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{69\rlb{}}
\cell{12\rlb{}}
\cell{12\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{49\rlb{}}
\cell{58\rlb{}}
\cell{24\rlb{}}
\erow
%R21B20
\brow
\alignR\cell{114\rlb{}}
\cell{95\rlb{}}
\cell{113\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{17\rlb{}}
\cell{54\rlb{\textsuperscript{6}}}
\cell{34\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{70\rlb{}}
\cell{40\rlb{}}
\cell{11\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{66\rlb{}}
\cell{22\rlb{}}
\cell{33\rlb{}}
\erow
%R22B21
\brow
\alignR\cell{112\rlb{}}
\cell{103\rlb{}}
\cell{74\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{10\rlb{}}
\cell{27\rlb{}}
\cell{31\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{27\rlb{}}
\cell{28\rlb{}}
\cell{10\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{65\rlb{}}
\cell{48\rlb{}}
\cell{57\rlb{}}
\erow
%R23B22
\brow
\alignR\cell{53\rlb{}}
\cell{85\rlb{}}
\cell{111\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{11\rlb{}}
\cell{71\rlb{}}
\cell{69\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{79\rlb{}}
\cell{39\rlb{}}
\cell{14\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{64\rlb{}}
\cell{66\rlb{}}
\cell{61\rlb{}}
\erow
%R24B23
\brow
\alignR\cell{80\rlb{}}
\cell{73\rlb{}}
\cell{87\rlb{\textsuperscript{3}}}
\cell{}
\cell{12\rlb{}}
\cell{76\rlb{}}
\cell{68\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{82\rlb{}}
\cell{29\rlb{}}
\cell{6\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{61\rlb{}}
\cell{60\rlb{}}
\cell{48\rlb{}}
\erow
%R25B24
\brow
\alignR\cell{97\rlb{}}
\cell{101\rlb{}}
\cell{97\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{15\rlb{}}
\cell{44\rlb{}}
\cell{41\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{84\rlb{}}
\cell{31\rlb{}}
\cell{64\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{48\rlb{}}
\cell{110\rlb{}}
\cell{60\rlb{}}
\erow
%R26B25
\brow
\alignR\cell{91\rlb{}}
\cell{99\rlb{}}
\cell{88\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{6\rlb{}}
\cell{50\rlb{}}
\cell{71\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{30\rlb{}}
\cell{42\rlb{}}
\cell{28\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{5\rlb{}}
\cell{49\rlb{}}
\cell{66\rlb{}}
\erow
%R27B26
\brow
\alignR\cell{85\rlb{}}
\cell{82\rlb{}}
\cell{80\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{37\rlb{}}
\cell{20\rlb{}}
\cell{52\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{29\rlb{}}
\cell{10\rlb{}}
\cell{23\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{9\rlb{\textsuperscript{10}}}
\cell{9\rlb{}}
\cell{49\rlb{}}
\erow
%R28B27
\brow
\cell{95\rlb{}}
\cell{81\rlb{}}
\cell{81\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{31\rlb{}}
\cell{26\rlb{}}
\cell{50\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{83\rlb{}}
\cell{34\rlb{}}
\cell{22\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{1\rlb{\textsuperscript{11}}}
\cell{5\rlb{}}
\cell{9\rlb{}}
\erow
%R29B28
\brow
\cell{106\rlb{}}
\cell{53\rlb{}}
\cell{84\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{34\rlb{}}
\cell{15\rlb{}}
\cell{45\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{2\rlb{}}
\cell{35\rlb{}}
\cell{21\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{...\rlb{}}
\cell{...\rlb{}}
\cell{...\rlb{}}
\erow
%R30B29
\brow
\cell{101\rlb{}}
\cell{84\rlb{}}
\cell{86\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{39\rlb{}}
\cell{19\rlb{}}
\cell{44\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{8\rlb{}}
\cell{7\rlb{}}
\cell{17\rlb{}}
\cell{}
\cell{...\rlb{}}
\cell{...\rlb{}}
\cell{...\rlb{}}
\erow

\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite complicated. For whole table, we may use `\foreach` to shorten TikZ code.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering   
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=.5]
\path[every node/.style={left=-11pt}]
(0,0)  node{196} 
(0,-1) node{8}
(0,-2) node{73} 
(1,0)  node{6}
(1,-1) node{74}
(1,-2) node{111}
(2,0)  node[left=-5pt]{103\footnotemark} 
(2,-1) node{100}
(2,-2) node{99}
(3,0)  node{75}
(3,-1) node{104}
(3,-2) node{77};

\def\c{2}
\path[every node/.style={rotate=90,align=center,scale=.8}] 
(0,\c+.5) node{According to\\Jalaluddin}
(1,\c+.5) node{According to\\Noeldcke}
(2,\c+.5) node{According to\\Muir}
(3,\c+.5) node{Jalaluddin};

\draw[shift={(-.5,.5)}]
(1,0)--+(-90:3)--+(90:2*\c)
(2,0)--+(-90:3)--+(90:2*\c)
(3,0)--+(-90:3)--+(90:2*\c)
(4,0)--+(-90:3)--+(90:2*\c) 
(4,-3) rectangle (0,0) rectangle (4,2*\c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Table of things.} 
\end{table}
\footnotetext{This is the first footnote inside the table.} 

This is the second footnote \footnote{This is second footnote!}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. However I managed to manually type in the footnotes horizontally (rather than the natural vertically) as it's a static document that is being retyped, and I can change the footnote marker. It is for the record, and for the general use of others, a more correct (but complex) solution. Thanks